# .position() doesn't point to the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have code like this:

```html
<div id="item-menu">
  <ul style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">
    <li id="item-1">1</li>
    <li id="item-2">2</li>
    <li id="item-3">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get each item position relative to the container. In this example I will get each `<li>` position relative to the `<ul>`, right?

What should I do to get position of item-1 --> top: 10, left: 20?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to add the style position:relative for your

```
  <ul style="position:relative;   padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">
```

then

```
$('#item-menu ul li').each(function(){
    console.info( $(this).position());
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `.first()`?

Comment: @dzejkej removed, that's just my test

Comment: @Xander for this case and this question, he wants to get the relative position of the li elements

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't be simpler. Simply call the [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method on the `li`s:

```
var position = $("#item-?").position();
```

Returns an object with properties `top` and `left`. You'll also need to set the `ul` to `position: relative` in your CSS.

```
#item-menu { position: relative; }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ByZRV/2/

Comment: yeah i did. but in mine, i always get position relative to the document. saying, that my `ul` above is 100px gap from the top of document..
I always get item-1 position --> top: 110, left: 20;
intead of --> top: 10, left: 20

do you why this kind happening?

Comment: @DavidRozando This is dependent on the `CSS` definitions you've applied to your document. To get the position relative to the `ul` give the `ul` an explicit `position` definition; allowing child `li`s to be positioned relative to the `ul`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to compute the location of an element:

```
var offset = $('#item-1').position();

alert(offset.left + ', ' + offset.top); // 20, 10
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/WNLp6/1)